# On Samsung mobile phones, how does its USB host know when to charge the phone and when to power the connected device?

Tags: power-supply, usb, charger

How do mobile phones (Samsung, in particular) distinguish between being charged and having to power the connected USB device (i.e. flash memory stick)?

Comment: I may be divulging my lack of knowledge for all things cell phone, but please explain the setup in a bit more detail so dolts like me can better understand the issue that you are observing.  We are common and ever present.  For instance, a flash memory stick needs no power if it is idle.  Also, why not charge... and do stuff simultaneously?  Is the phone/host not capable of that?

Comment: The setup is quite simple:

A Samsung phone is connected through the standard data transfer usb cable to another device (that requires5V). The device is just a passive appliance, like an LED torch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done with the USB OTG. Usb mini and micro have a OTG pin that the phone uses to know if it's supposed to be host or slave.

Usb C has a more complicated signaling system but the idea is the same.